Me conecto con Proxychains pero no me cambia la ip
Hola estoy teniendo probemas con proxychains. Se conecta a tor pero cuando ejecuto proxychains, no me da error pero tampoco me cambia la ip. Configuro el archivo .conf como recomiendan con el Socks5 en el puerto 9050 dynamic_chain conecto con firefox y me sigue apareciendo mi ip real. Cambié la MV de bridge a nat y nada. No se si tambien deberia configurar el firefox.  ¿Alguien sabe porque no esta funcionando? no me da ningun mensaje de error
